# How to desrialize the output message from kafka consumer in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation, appium, kafka-consumer-api

I am a beginner with Kafka. I am using kafka consumer in my automation, I am able to get the messages but it is serialized data(in bytes). I would like to deserialize it and get the message in pretty/json format. How should I do it in ruby, any leads? Also I am using following code to stop the consumer from reading but my automation does not stop there and it keeps running:

```
 consumer.subscribe(topic)
  trap('TERM') {consumer.stop}
```

Thanks,
RV

Comment: can you post some code showing how you are trying to access the messages e.g. `consumer.each_message {#...}`? What does the "serialized data" look like can you post an example? What library are you using for Kafka access `ruby-kafka`?

Comment: @engineersmnky yes I am using ruby-kafka. The code is as follows:
 consumer.each_message do |message|
 puts message.offset, message.key, message.value
end

Messages are in bytes.